# Mongoose query on date intervals

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my Mongoose Schema "photographer" i have a property with nested objects that describes when the photographer is not available, made as follows:

```
const photographer = new Schema({
  _id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ...
  busy: [{startDate : Date, endDate : Date}],
  ...
  })
```

I need to query all the documents, given a date, that represent photographers free in a that given time. I don't know how to write the right query. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you please post some sample collection and output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make a range query. Switch `$gt` and `$lt` depends on you program. For example:

```
var myDate = new Date(req.query.date); // 
Photographer.find({
    $and: [
        {'busy.startDate': {$lt: myDate}},
        {'busy.endDate': {$gt: myDate}}
    ]
}, (err, photographers) => {})
```

Or, simple way is get all photographers first, and then make conditions to check whether a photographer is busy on provided day or not.

Comment: I did like this but i also used the $elemMatch operator in my query to iterate over multiple records